# How to reinstall NetBeans? all the available components( packs and runtimes) are already installed, How to proceed?

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, installation

Problem with NetBeans re-installation( the first one worked fine): All of the available components are already installed. click cancel to exit the installer. No way to proceed!

Previously I downloaded and installed the window version of  NetBeans IDE 8.1  with "All- a full download option (215 MB)" , which contains all the runtimes and technologies available for the NetBeans IDE. https://netbeans.org/downloads/. a weak ago i restored my computer to an earlier point in time. after restore my recently installed applications are deleted including NetBeans, my favorite IDE to run java.

When I try to install it now, I got a problem! it says all the available components( packs and runtimes) are already installed. And I have no way to go forward. The "Next" button is disabled.All of the available components are already installed. click cancel to exit the installer. No Next button.  please see the picture 
 [NetBeans IDE 8.1 Installer welcome snapschot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vL95C.png)

Comment: Even though your program is no longer there in your icons, is the program listed in the "uninstall program" list in your settings for windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to "C:\Program Files" and look for "NetBeans" folder, then delete that folder and try reinstall it, it should work fine this time.
Also,this can help [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansMultipleInstancesInstallation)

Answer (score 2):

On debian you might try go

> /usr/local/netbeans-8.2/uninstall.sh

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the glassfish server and the Apache server from the program files too, if the above don't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).